# Roaming Manager Package in. Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am facing "Roaming Manager package. " issue. This occurred after I tried to install AjaxControltoolkit which was not installed properly. To resolve the issue I tried uninstalling it,repair and resetting command option.but I see it whenever I try to open the project.

Please help me

Comment: What error, specifically, are you getting? We don't have enough information to help. You might want to reference the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem

```
  <entry>
<record>455</record>
<time>2016/06/06 19:04:28.244</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [Roaming Manager Package]</description>
<guid>{54888390-2C04-4B04-B451-3166730C75BA}</guid>
<hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
<errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo>
```

Following a lead I found in another thread I removed this key from the registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\AutoLoadPackages\{54888390-2C04-4B04-B451-3166730C75BA}
```

Then I restarted and the error went away and ActivityLog.xml was did not updated

Then it finally clicked what the Roaming Manager Package was...

It's the synchronized settings in Options --> Environment

So I went there and I got this:

[image]

I clicked Yes Selected another setting and then re-selected the "synchronized settings" option and got this:

[image]

**Now, the error when you open is gone at this point.  But the error when you select the synchronized settings option remains.
So you could just leave it at this if you don't care about this option**

I'd like to use this option so I continued my research until I ran out of time, but I was able find these registry locations

NOTE: You can have several of the 14.0_Config folders, I think they are based on your workspace but not sure yet, like this:

[image]

It's just something to note as you look at the screen shots because some come from different keys

here they are and I'll try to follow up when I get a chance but I don't know when that will be

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]